# symfony2 the Doctrine of LeftJoin Query error:Call to a member function add() on a non-object

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Error: Call to a member function add() on a non-object in E:\xampp\htdocs\symfony\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection.php line 177

Will leftjoin how to write the statement was correct?

**BlogRepoistory.php**

```
public function getLatestBlogs($limit=null){
    $qb=$this->createQueryBuilder('blog')
        ->select('blog','c')
        ->leftJoin('blog.comments','c')
        ->orderBy('blog.created','DESC')
        ;
    if (false === is_null($limit))
        $qb->setMaxResults($limit);
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

**PageController.php**

```
/**
 * @Route("/",name="homepage")
 * @Template()
 */
public function indexAction(){
    $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $blogs=$em->getRepository('BloggerBlogBundle:Blog')->getLatestBlogs();

    return array('blogs'=>$blogs);
}
```

**Comment Entity:**

```
class Comment{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=100)
 */
protected $user;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text")
 */
protected $comment;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 */
protected $approved;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Blog",inversedBy="comments")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="blog_id",referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $blog;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
protected $created;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
protected $updated;
```

**BlogEntity:**

```
class Blog{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $title;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=100)
 */
protected $author;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text")
 */
protected $blog;

/**
 * @var
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=20)
 */
protected $image;

/**
 * @var
 * @ORM\Column(type="text")
 */
protected $tags;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment",mappedBy="blog")
 */
protected $comments = array();

/**
 * @var
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
protected $created;

/**
 * @var
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
protected $updated;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `array` in blog class. Take a closer look a this part

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment",mappedBy="blog")
 */
protected $comments;
```

Hope it will help someone else